# Xamarin Base View for all other View

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to create a base class that derives from the `Xamarin.Forms.View` class and that have common properties to all other class that derives from this base class.

This is the sample that I have create:

```
public class VolosBaseView : View {

    public bool Required {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RequiredProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly BindableProperty RequiredProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Required), typeof(bool), typeof(VolosTextEntryView));

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null) {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == RequiredProperty.PropertyName) {
            if (Required) {
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightYellow;
            } else {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need one class for each `Xamarin.Forms` view class (`Entry`, `Picker`, `Switch`, etc..) that derives from this base class, but if I create a class like this (this is for `Entry`):

```
public class VolosTextEntryView : VolosBaseView {

    public VolosTextEntryView() {
    }
}
```

my view lost all property of th `Entry` base class.

How can I create the base class with common properties and create all other class that derives from it and from one of the other `Xamarin.Forms` view class such Entry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it happen the way you said it isn't possible. C# can't have multiple inheritance.

You can simulate it using [the pattern suggested here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C)

Despite this, it's probable you can solve the ploblem you describe creating an interface, then, for example, your View `MyViewEntry` should inherites from `Entry` and implement IBaseView.